# Cannot access ActvityCompat Api

Tags: android

Every Activity that I create that extends AppCompatActivity result in an error

error: cannot access ActivityCompatApi23
class file for android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompatApi23 not found

I cant find a solution for this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is conflicted Support library version in your app/module `build.gradle`. You need to use the same version for all of them. And also check for other dependencies which could implicitly using support library.